# how to reset 'key' to the beginning of the amazon s3 bucket object list and traverse it again in python (aws-lambda)?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

How to iterate s3 bucket list again by resetting key to the beginning of the list?

```
for key in bucket.objects.all():
    print(key.key)
```

Comment: Call `.all()` again? If you iterate over it more than once it may be worth reading the iterator into a list.

Comment: Can you please explain it in detail?

Comment: Which part? For the first one, just have a second for loop. For the second, `list(bucket.objects.all())`.

Comment: input- list(bucket.objects.all())                  
                 output -           [s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='a', key='5.jpg'), s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name=a', key='p1.png'), s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='a, key='p2.png'), s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='a', key='p3.png'), s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='a', key='p4.png'), s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='a', key='p5.png'), s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='a', key='p6.png'), s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='a', key='p7.png'), s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='a', key='pen4.png')]

Comment: Yes, that looks about right. Do you still have a question?

Comment: It worked Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can return a Python list of all Keys in the bucket:

```
import boto3

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='ap-southeast-2')

# Get a list of all Keys in the bucket
bucket = s3_resource.Bucket('my-bucket')
key_list = [object.key for object in bucket.objects.all()]

# Do something here with key_list
for key in key_list:
    print(f'I found {key}')
```